# Matlab cputime with kmeans return 0

Tags: matlab, k-means, cpu-time

I am measuring the cputime taken by kmeans algorithm for each iteration using *cputime* feature. However, some iterations return cputime = 0. Here's my implementation:

```
   load fisheriris;
   [~,C] = kmeans(meas, 3, 'options',statset('MaxIter', 1),'Display', 'off');
   results=[];
   for i = 1:15
          t=cputime;
          [~,C] = kmeans(meas, 3, 'options',statset('MaxIter', 1),'Start',C, 'Display', 'off');
          elapsedCPUTime=cputime-t;
          results=[results;elapsedCPUTime];
   end
```

This is the results I got for 15 iterations: 0, 0, 0.046875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0.03125. My first thought is that the computational time was too quick, hence 0 second. Is it true? If so, how can we achieve more precise cputime?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cputime.html):

> To measure performance, it is recommended that you use the timeit or
>   tic and toc functions. For more information, see [Using tic and toc Versus the cputime Function](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html#bt1ltzm).

Following that link:

> Time a significant enough portion of code. Ideally, the code you are timing should take more than 1/10 second to run.

Try running `kmeans` in a loop.

```
load fisheriris;
[~,C] = kmeans(meas, 3, 'options',statset('MaxIter', 1),'Display', 'off');
results=[];
for ii = 1:15
      t=cputime;
      for k = 1:100
          [~,Ctemp] = kmeans(meas, 3, 'options',statset('MaxIter', 1),'Start',C, 'Display', 'off');
      end
      elapsedCPUTime=(cputime-t)/100;
      C = Ctemp;
      results=[results;elapsedCPUTime];
end
```

Using `i` as the loop variable might yield [unexpected results](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html?searchHighlight=i&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), which is why I changed it to `ii`.

Comment: I want to measure both wall-clock time and cpu time.

Comment: @PhuLai See the edit.